# Eclipse e4 issue while exporting it

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am testing the eclipse e4 framework and i try to export a simple hello world program the program compiles and shows the window in eclipse once i export and run the exe it generates a log with error report unable to find the package

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_26
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2012-02-15 23:24:46.725
!MESSAGE Product com.test.test.test.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-02-15 23:24:46.738
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 0):

The log output `"!MESSAGE Product com.test.test.test.product could not be found."` could be the result of *a missing bundle*.

Make sure that the *list of required plug-ins and fragments* is complete. You can open that list by double clicking the "product" file of the eclipse plugin and then navigating to the tab "Dependencies". There's a simple button "Add Required Plug-Ins" that can be used to add all needed plug-ins automatically.